# cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android

My app crashes whenever I launch this activity and throws the error :

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar**

Below is my code, how can I fix this?

```
package com.example.irecipe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView toolbar_title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

        toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar_title = findViewById(R.id.toolBar_title);
        toolbar_title.setText("Recipe");

    }

}
```

Comment: Use an androidx toolbar inside your layout not a support toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML for Toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white_grey"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_top_right"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Java Code for Toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }
```

Hope this will work for you and Its tested and working properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
```

to:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)` from the line: `toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar)`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this `(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)`, so it will be like `toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);`.

Answer (score 0):

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar**

I've 2 solutions you can try:

1. Change the import of `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` to `import android.widget.Toolbar`  and remove the casting, `toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);`
2. change the layout implementation of `<android.widget.Toolbar...` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...`