# Im not sure why i am getting this error. I am not casting from two different toolbars

Tags: android, androidx

here is my code

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

here is error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bloodbank/com.example.bloodbank.CategorySelectedActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share your xml to us? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973044/cannot-be-cast-to-androidx-appcompat-widget-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity extended from the androidx **AppCompatActivity** and in your imports you are importing exactly androidx Toolbar

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```